# Can I (as the client) maintain an open connection (without closing) to a website (or server) for 10 minutes?

Tags: google-chrome, networking, tcp, http-status-code-500, http-status-code-503

We are retrieving information from a particular website every minute throughout the day. At a particular time during the day, the website receives a surge of requests from other users and we can no longer access it to continue retrieving information until sometime after about 10 minutes after which invalidates our research. We receive errors such as 500 Internal Server Error and 503 first byte timeout. Presumably, the servers hosting that website are overloaded by the surge in new requests from other users.

Is there anything we can do from the client-side to either:
A. prioritize our connection to that server, or
B. maintain an open connection to that server to assure we can continue receiving information?

We are using Chrome via selenium to access the site and running a python script to retrieve the data.

Comment: Remember that TCP does not have clients or servers. TCP connections are peer connections where each peer is equal, and either peer can close the connection.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 1.1 or higher version can use long connection, it will send a heart-beat packet to keep the connection alive.